# Switch features enabled, but not showing in configuration

Tags: switch, hp, network-discovery

My question may seem odd, but please entertain me:

When I SHOW RUN on my HP switch, there is zero configuration information for, let's use in this example, LLDP (link layer discovery protocol).  However, it's enabled on the switch.

I would think any switch/router/etc. would have a feature list, but most everything is turned off unless appearing in the configuration file.

How can I determine what else might be enabled on my device?  Perhaps other protocols/features which aren't necessary intrinsic to basic operation (such as ARP, I wouldn't expect to "enable ARP")?  I think, as a curious admin, it's good to know.

Comment: Most systems do not include defaults in the configuration. Check your manual for commands to see the defaults as well, if possible.

Comment: Ricky, I saw no section in the manual that covers "stuff enabled by default" if you will.  Any ideas?  Looks like I'm down to the "manual hunt", eh?

Comment: Which "hp switch" are you talking about? There are many different flavors.

Comment: Various ProCurve models.  I'm just going through all the options now to make a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to check your vendors documentation as to what is enabled or disabled by default. On Cisco devices for example CDP is enabled, but LLDP is not enabled by default.

There are some protocols which have become enabled or disabled by default differently as OS versions. For instance Finger, you used to have to manually disable this but now it is disabled by default.

I think this is part based on how much configuration is necessary for the protocol and it's popularity or use.